# Private NPM: How can the latest version of a module be installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, repository, semantic-versioning

Using private `npm`, common commands seem not to work:

- `npm install` without a specific `@version` :: [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4984)
- `npm outdated` :: [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11869)
- `npm update` :: [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727)
- `npm view <private-package-name> versions` :: (haven't found issue yet)

  - also note that `npm v`, `npm show`, and `npm info` are [aliases](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) that likewise don't work

Frequently, I will not know the latest version of a private module my team maintains. I would fall back on one of the commands listed above, but they seem inoperative. How can I install a package without knowing the latest version?

Comment: What is your npm version?

Comment: @Syc npm => `v3.10.9`. node => `v7.0.0`.

Comment: What error do you get using `npm install`? And what happens when you try @jettpleyn solution in the answers?

Comment: @Syc no that doesn't work.

Comment: @Syc Error `npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: <package name>`. It does list the available versions I see now, but that gets confusing when when there are many, many versions and I don't think the user should be forced to sort through them all.

Comment: you can try to clean your npm cache via `npm cache clear` and `npm rebuild` and then try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ultimately arrived at was to use the `@*` syntax when running the install:

```
npm install --save my-off_the_hook-module@*
```

This seems kind of sloppy to me but it does save the latest version of the module in a manner that is, so far as I can tell, equivalent to the more familiar (and my opinion more explicit) `@latest` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, installing latest package would be:

```
npm install <package_name>@latest --save
```

Comment: Thanks though! Of all the commands I tried, this foolishly slipped my mind! :P

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), running `npm install package-name` is supposed to install the latest version the registry knows about. This may be different for private npm instances, but there doesn't appear to be so as they reference private repos in the documentation as well.

> `npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>:`
>
> Install the version of the package that is referenced by the specified
>   tag. If the tag does not exist in the registry data for that package,
>   then this will fail.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> npm install sax@latest
> npm install @myorg/mypackage@latest
> ```

*From: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install on Nov 23, 2016*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you have a read of the issues I linked and comments I've posted? I'll incorporated them into the main question as soon as I'm off mobile: `@latest` doesn't work either :/

Comment: Yes I did, Though they are closed, I really don't see why they should be. They look like they are standing issues, esp. in light of you dealing with it. 

Is your private registry customized or misconfigured at all?